# Left join not returning values

Tags: mysql, left-join

This query is giving values as `null` for `accessories_type.type` but this table has values:

```
SELECT accessories.id, accessories.name, accessories_type.type
FROM accessories
LEFT JOIN accessories_type ON accessories_type.type = accessories.accessories_type_id;
```

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: are the nulls on accessories whose type_ID doesn't exist in accessories_Type?  Example Type ID is 10 in accessories but i accessories_Type there is no such ID?  (if so this implies there is no key relationship then)  consider adding accessories.accessories_Type_ID to the select of your query.  It will help identify if its a missing value in the type table.

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to have anything wrong, you need to post more information like table, data example, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a little strange.  The value `accessories_type.type` in the `select` clause is the same as being used for the join.

Assuming there are no duplicate rows in the type table, you can get the same effect by doing:

```
select id, name, accessories_type_id
from accessories
```

Your queries is additionally looking for matches in the second table.  When there are no matches, you are getting NULL.

Normally, I would expect something like `accessories_type.typename` in the `select`.  This gives me an idea.  Perhaps you really mean:

```
SELECT accessories.id, accessories.name, accessories_type.type
FROM accessories
LEFT JOIN accessories_type ON accessories_type.id = accessories.accessories_type_id;
```

That is, you should be joining on the `id`.  You are joining on the `name` and there is no match (in general).